# Is there a way to change three.js canvas whenever you switch to a different page?

Tags: typescript, three.js, sveltekit

I have 2 pages with different three.js scripts and geometries but when I switch pages, the canvas appears to stay the same. Any fix for this?

Tried to put `window.location.reload()` at the top of the script, I expected it to just reload the page and have the three.js script update, but it just routed back to `/`.